# Why does MS Graph reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail call not returning any data?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

We've built a PowerShell report that uses this MS Graph report: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D180')‎](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period=%27D180%27)%E2%80%8E).

Recentry it stopped returning data. We're just getting the column header now. I've double checked the API permissions for the app registion in Azure and reports.read.all is present. I've removed and re-added the permission to see. Didn't tried recreating the App Registration yet.

Here is the part of the script that call getSharePointSiteUsageDetail. $Sites variable at the last line doesn't contain anything after running this:

```
$AppId = "VALID-APP-ID-HERE"
$TenantId = "VALID-TENANT-ID-HERE"
$AppSecret = 'VALID-APP-SECRET-HERE'

# Build the request to get the OAuth 2.0 access token
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = @{
    client_id     = $AppId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"}
# Request token
$tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
# Unpack Access Token
$token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}
$ctype = "application/json"


# Get SharePoint files usage data
$SPOFilesReportsURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D180')"
$Sites = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $SPOFilesReportsURI -Headers $Headers -Method Get -ContentType $ctype) -Replace "ï»¿", "" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: After you run your script you should check the values of $token, $tokenRequest, and $Sites.  One of those should have a clue.

Comment: Yes I check the value for @Sites and it's empty. If I run this (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $SPOFilesReportsURI -Headers $Headers -Method Get -ContentType $ctype) I get only the column header.